# Refreshing stale data in next js app router without refreshing page

Tags: next.js, app-router

The new App router in Next emphasises and encourages fetching data on the server through server components. However I can't find documentation for a strategy to refresh said data on the client side without refreshing the entire page.

Here is a contrived example. Say I have a library app that displays all the books in my library. I want to be able to add a book to my library and update the client with the server side generated ID with having to do another server side render.

Is there a common pattern for this requirement?